# It shows me my post type but my pages don't

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I made a directory and I wanted it to be displayed alphabetically by last name, I made it work but now you only see my custom post type and my pages don't show them...

Appreciate your help

````
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'dr_order_content' );
function dr_order_content( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() ){
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'directorio-doctores' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'apellido' );
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'CHAR' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
  return $query;
}
```
`
````

Comment: meta key `apellido` should exist in all the posts that you have otherwise rest of the posts not having `apellido` meta key will not show in query results.

Comment: how can I solve that?
Thanks